# mute не работает

Tags: python, discord

Делаю команду мута, всё работает отлично. Почти всё. Когда проходит заданное время, бот выдёт такую ошибку:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sleep'

```
# мут
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute1(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, *, reason="причина не указана"):
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="mute")
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await member.add_roles(mute_role)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="╔=============================╗", colour=discord.Color.red(),
                          description=f"{member.mention} был замьючен на {time} минут по следующей причине: {reason}")
    embed.set_footer(text="Операция прошла успешно")
    embed.set_image(url="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a9/0f/e2/a90fe21457dbc5d06b8579d55d7cbda1.gif")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    time.sleep(time)
    await member.remove_roles(mute_role)
```

Comment: У вас локальная переменная `time` замещает ту, которую вы импортировали через `import time`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, *, reason="причина не указана"):
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="mute")
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await member.add_roles(mute_role)
    await member.send(f"Вас замьютили на сервере {ctx.guild.name}\nПричина: {reason}\nВремя мута: {time} минут")
    embed = discord.Embed(title="╔=============================╗", colour=discord.Color.red(),
                          description=f"{member.mention} был замьючен на {time} минут по следуйщей причине: {reason}")
    embed.set_footer(text="Операция прошла успешно")
    embed.set_image(url="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a9/0f/e2/a90fe21457dbc5d06b8579d55d7cbda1.gif")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(10) #ошибка была тут
    await member.remove_roles(mute_role)
```